# CSS background color based on select value of dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 dropdown list.first dropdown list is for choosing color and second dropdown list is that which have been populated images file from directory.what i want to do is when color from first dropdown list is selected the corresponding color should be save as background color of second dropdownlist selected Image in that directory.How can i do that..Below is the code i have done so for

```
<Asp:dropdownlist id="ddlColor"  runat="server">
<asp:ListItem Value="#00FFFF">Cyan</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="#FF00FF">Magenta</asp:ListItem
 </Asp:dropdownlist>

<Asp:dropdownlist id="ddlImages" runat="server" style="width: 275px">
 </Asp:dropdownlist>
```

Code for Populating Image dropdownlist

```
 String[] Images = Directory.GetFiles(MapPath("~/Images/Layers/"), "*.png");
        for (int i = 0; i < Images.Length; i++)
            Images[i] = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Images[i]);
        ddlImages.DataSource = Images;
        ddlImages.DataBind();
```

Comment: From memory, I don't believe that WebForms allows direct access to any styling information on individual `OPTION`s; you will need to code this manually.

Comment: @AdrianWragg you mean to say  it not possible to save first dropdown selected value as background image of second dropdown selected image

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I'm afraid - did you mean "background colour of second dropdown's selected item"? It's possible, just tricky; you may need to use a custom control rather than the out-of-the-box `asp:drodown`.

Comment: have you tried using jquery/JavaScript as an alternative. A few lines of code would do what you require

Answer (score 0):

You can make it so that after you select a colour the page changes to the version where the specific colour is selected then just make it check what colour is selected and depending on the color previously selected the second dropdown list changes.